# PhpUnit not showing a stack trace for a php fatal error

Tags: php, phpunit

PhpUnit is currently not showing the stack trace for PHP errors that occur in the code.

How do I configure it to do so?

Comment: Can you provide some sample code as I'm not sure i understand you right. (it seems to work for me, maybe i misunderstood)

Comment: As in, I get a PHP Fatal error:  Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in file.php on line x, so I want to see its stack trace to see what's going on. PhpUnit is showing the final error and not the full trace.

Comment: @edorian: I've occasionally seen this happen when the phpunit's error handler chokes on recursively nested objects with references between one another. If it ends up running out of memory in the output buffer you can end up without a trace (though still an entry in the error log).

Comment: in my experience, you're going to need to follow code step by step in your situation.

Comment: jerry rig it to stop the code and stack trace when it reaches a certain condition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PHPUnit uses an error handler function to trap and display errors, but from the PHP manual on [error handlers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php),

> The following error types cannot be
>   handled with a user defined function:
>   E_ERROR, E_PARSE, E_CORE_ERROR,
>   E_CORE_WARNING, E_COMPILE_ERROR,
>   E_COMPILE_WARNING, and most of
>   E_STRICT raised in the file where
>   set_error_handler() is called.

If you are running tests in a separate process, PHPUnit will get the error and message from the interpreter, but there will be no stack trace available. This is simply a limitation of the PHP interpreter. Fatal means *fatal.*

Answer (score 3):

This is a lame yet effective way that I've found to get a stack dump when php doesn't give one. I have this in a classed called DebugUtil.

```
        /**
         * This is for use when you have the UBER-LAME...
         * "PHP Fatal error:  Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached,
         * aborting!  in Lame.php(1273)
         * ...which just craps out leaving you without a stack trace.
         * At the line in the file where it finally spazzes out add
         * something like...
         * DebugUtil::dumpStack('/tmp/lame');
         * It will write the stack into that file every time it passes that
         * point and when it eventually blows up (and probably long before) you
         * will be able to see where the problem really is.
         */
        public static function dumpStack($fileName)
        {
            $stack = "";
            foreach (debug_backtrace() as $trace)
            {
                if (isset($trace['file'])  &&
                    isset($trace['line'])  &&
                    isset($trace['class']) &&
                    isset($trace['function']))
                {
                    $stack .= $trace['file']     . '#' .
                              $trace['line']     . ':' .
                              $trace['class']    . '.' .
                              $trace['function'] . "\n";
                }
            }
            file_put_contents($fileName, $stack);
        }
```