# Selenium don't show failed number lines

Tags: php, selenium, tdd, phpunit, mamp

I have Selenium server working with PHPUnit on a MAMP local server.

When an Assert fail, the failed number line is not showing, instead I see a phpunit number line.

When I execute a "phpunit only" test I can see the number line of the failed assert.

PHPUnit only test

```
$ cd '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my-client/tests' && phpunit -c 'phpunit.xml'  '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my-client/tests/controllers/homeTest.php'
PHPUnit 3.6.10 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my-client/tests/phpunit.xml

.

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 8.00Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) HomeTest::test_get_sections
Failed asserting that Array (
    blah, blah, blah
    )
) is identical to Array (blah, blah, blah2
    )
).

/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my-client/tests/controllers/homeTest.php:56
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/phpunit:46

FAILURES!
Tests: 2, Assertions: 3, Failures: 1.
```

PHPUnit Selenium test

```
$ cd '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my-client/tests' && phpunit -c 'phpunit.xml'  

'/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my-client/tests/views/af_web_Test.php'
PHPUnit 3.6.10 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my-client/tests/phpunit.xml

E

Time: 2 seconds, Memory: 8.75Mb

There was 1 error:

1) af_web_Test::test_crear_una_af_nueva_y_validar_el_valor_por_defecto_de_los_campos
Current URL: http://localhost:8888/my-client/index.php/home/view

Failed asserting that '' matches PCRE pattern "/0/".

/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/phpunit:46

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 6, Errors: 1.
```

Comment: I suggest you turn off colors so that the ANSI codes aren't displayed (do not use `--colors`), see http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/textui.html - not that's your issue here, just saying, might help you to debug things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had the same problem (albeit on a LAMP server), as I quite rely on these line numbers along with screenshots to figure out exactly what's going wrong in my tests. The bug, which I assume this is, is apparently reported. See https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/issues/81 for reference.

As a **temporary** workaround I've forced the line number into the error message in the exception that is being thrown (because the line number can of course be found in the trace). As a side-effect, most exceptions are rethrown and I am only throwing PHPUnit_Framework_Error, but at least I get the line number in the output. As a temporary workaround until this is fixed, this works for me.

To achieve this, I extend **PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase** with my own SeleniumTestCase, and put these functions in it:

Very slightly modified version of this function for my own use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6608751

```
protected function dumpStack(Exception $e) {
    $stack = '';
    foreach ($e->getTrace() as $trace) {
        if (isset($trace['file'])        &&
            isset($trace['line'])        &&
            isset($trace['class'])       &&
            isset($trace['function']))
        {
            $stack .= PHP_EOL .
                $trace['file']     . ':' .
                $trace['line']     . ' ' .
                $trace['class']    . '::' .
                $trace['function'];
        }
    }
    return $stack;
}
```

I override **onNotSuccessfulTest** from **PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase**:

```
protected function onNotSuccessfulTest(Exception $e) {
    try {
        parent::onNotSuccessfulTest($e);
    }
    catch (PHPUnit_Framework_IncompleteTestError $e) {
        // Don't do anything with the incomplete test exception
        throw $e;
    }
    catch (PHPUnit_Framework_SkippedTestError $e) {
        // Don't do anything with the skipped test exception
        throw $e;
    }
    catch (Exception $e_parent) {
        // Include line number for specific test file in error
        $error_msg = chr(10).chr(10).$this->dumpStack($e);

        throw new PHPUnit_Framework_Error($e_parent->getMessage().$error_msg, $e_parent->getCode(), $e_parent->getFile(), $e_parent->getLine(), $e_parent->getTrace());
     }
}
```

I don't like this hack, so if anyone has a better solution, I'd be happy to hear it!

**UPDATE:
I forgot to mention this initially: You of course have to make the tests extend your own custom SeleniumTestCase, and not the PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase.**